# How to provide some library from maven to Google Compile-Testing

Tags: java, testing, junit5, annotation-processing, google-compile-testing

I'm writing a tests for my annotation processor with Google Compile-Testing and JUnit.

How to provide some libraries, which present at maven(as example, `"somegroup:somelib:1.0"`), to compilation?

```java
Compilation compilation = Compiler.javac().withProcessors(new MyProcessor())
                .withClasspath(???) //What's there to use?
                .compile(
                        JavaFileObjects.forResource("path/to/SomeClass.java")
                        ...
                );
```

Comment: I solve it by providing downloaded libs like
`.withClasspath(ImmutableList.of(
                     new File("C:\\Users\\hohserg\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\io.netty\\netty-all\\4.1.25.Final\\d0626cd3108294d1d58c05859add27b4ef21f83b\\netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar")))`     But it look so spooky

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It can be reached by using `withClasspathFrom` for provide to test compilation all classes which available at test itself:

```java
Compilation compilation = Compiler.javac().withProcessors(new MyProcessor())
                .withClasspathFrom(this.getClass().getClassLoader())
                .compile(
                        JavaFileObjects.forResource("path/to/SomeClass.java")
```